# Python way to check how many SMS have been sent

Tags: python, email, time, count, sms

I have a python script in my check_mk installation to send E-Mails and SMS for virtual hosts and services in critical cases.
I want to ensure that not more than 15 SMS/E-Mails will be sent in an hour to avoid spam if a physical server was unreachable or down, so that a notification wont be sent for each VM and service.
Is there a way of doing that without a counter file? Maybe a running server?

I would do something like this:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
from os import environ


# parameters
hosts = ['192.168.1.10', '192.168.1.11']
login = 'user'
password = 'secret'
number = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'

def message():
    if environ['NOTIFY_WHAT'] == 'HOST':
        msg = "%s %s: %s (%s)" % (
            environ['NOTIFY_NOTIFICATIONTYPE'],
            environ['NOTIFY_HOSTNAME'],
            environ['NOTIFY_HOSTOUTPUT'],
            environ['NOTIFY_SHORTDATETIME'])
    elif environ['NOTIFY_WHAT'] == 'SERVICE':
        msg = "%s %s: %s %s (%s)" % (
            environ['NOTIFY_NOTIFICATIONTYPE'],
            environ['NOTIFY_HOSTNAME'],
            environ['NOTIFY_SERVICEDESC'],
            environ['NOTIFY_SERVICEOUTPUT'],
            environ['NOTIFY_SHORTDATETIME'])
    else:
        msg = "Unknown: " + environ['NOTIFY_WHAT']
    return msg

def sendSMS(receiver, message):
    args = {'login': login, 'pass': password, 'to': receiver, 'message': message}
    enc_args = urllib.urlencode(args)
    sent = False
    error = ''

    for host in hosts:
        url = 'http://%s/index.php/http_api/send_sms?%s' % (host, enc_args)
        if not sent:
            try:
                result = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
            except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
                print('sending sms via host %s failed: %s' % (host, str(e.code)))
            except urllib2.URLError, e:
                print('sending sms via host %s failed: %s' % (host, str(e.args)))
            else:
                if result.startswith('OK;'):
                    sent = True
                    print('SMS successfully sent via %s to %s.' % (host, receiver))
                    break
                else:
                    sent = False
                    print 'Sending SMS via host %s failed: %s' % (host, result.rstrip()))
    return

    message = message()
    sendSMS(number, message)
```

The script is read and executed by check_mk, it is controlled via WATO. So I have no power over the execution.

Many Thanks

Comment: How are you invoking the script? What's the code that sends the SMS? We need more information.

Comment: I edited my post and added how would I approach it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to be able to keep the count of how many sms has been sent within a given period of time. You could move your sendSMS function into a simple web service which your script just posts to. That way it can keep track of the rate that sendSMS is being called and act accordingly.

Another way would be to use redis as a place to store your count rather than a file.